# OPC UA Java Client SDK Integration in Android

Tags: java, android, opc, opc-ua

I want to develop an Android Application using OPC UA Java Client SDK. I already developed a Java Application and was able to make a connection between client and server but did not succeed to do the same in Android. Please help in this topic.If You have any source then shared with me.

Comment: Do you have any stacktraces or Log-Messages indicating any sort of error?

Comment: Yes I have i gave you the whole source code if you helped me on this topic\

Comment: Hi Fildor Do you have any idea about working on my topic ?

Comment: Just add the stacktrace to your question and the relevant code. Did you check that your App has enough rights?

Comment: I was already tested that code was working in my simple Java Application but whiel trying to Integrate the code in Android not able to connect with Server. i give the stack  trace and code also.

Comment: Hi Fildor Is it possible i provide you whole code for that and If you are able to give sometime then check that code also?